# JS World clock multiple conditions display

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I'm running a world clock script (NY,LONDON,TOKYO,SYDNEY) time. And on the page, next to the location name displays a RED/GREEN dot based on the market status if OPEN/CLOSE.
SO, I'm trying to setup a different conditions for each specific location, as for eg:

- NY market opens at 9AM and closes at 17PM
- LONDON opens at 8AM and closes at 16PM

...between this time the status displays the color (limegreen), if off this time it displays status color (red)...

Hope I made clear to understand, I'm desperate for long to fix this.

[image: world clock image]

```js
function worldClock(zone, region) {
  var dst = 0
  var time = new Date()
  var gmtMS = time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
  var gmtTime = new Date(gmtMS)
  var day = gmtTime.getDate()
  var month = gmtTime.getMonth()
  var year = gmtTime.getYear()
  if (year < 1000) {
    year += 1900
  }
  var monthArray = new Array("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
    "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
  var monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
  if (year % 4 == 0) {
    monthDays = new Array("31", "29", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
  }
  if (year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0) {
    monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
  }

  var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
  var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
  var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()

  var status = new Array("")

  if (hr >= 24) {
    hr = hr - 24
    day -= -1
  }
  if (hr < 0) {
    hr -= -24
    day -= 1
  }
  if (hr < 10) {
    hr = " " + hr
  }
  if (min < 10) {
    min = "0" + min
  }
  if (sec < 10) {
    sec = "0" + sec
  }
  if (day <= 0) {
    if (month == 0) {
      month = 11
      year -= 1
    } else {
      month = month - 1
    }
    day = monthDays[month]
  }
  if (day > monthDays[month]) {
    day = 1
    if (month == 11) {
      month = 0
      year -= -1
    } else {
      month -= -1
    }
  }
  if (region == "NAmerica") {
    var startDST = new Date()
    var endDST = new Date()
    startDST.setMonth(3)
    startDST.setHours(2)
    startDST.setDate(1)
    var dayDST = startDST.getDay()
    if (dayDST != 0) {
      startDST.setDate(8 - dayDST)
    } else {
      startDST.setDate(1)
    }
    endDST.setMonth(9)
    endDST.setHours(1)
    endDST.setDate(31)
    dayDST = endDST.getDay()
    endDST.setDate(31 - dayDST)
    var currentTime = new Date()
    currentTime.setMonth(month)
    currentTime.setYear(year)
    currentTime.setDate(day)
    currentTime.setHours(hr)
    if (currentTime >= startDST && currentTime < endDST) {
      dst = 1
    }
  }
  if (region == "Europe") {
    var startDST = new Date()
    var endDST = new Date()
    startDST.setMonth(2)
    startDST.setHours(1)
    startDST.setDate(31)
    var dayDST = startDST.getDay()
    startDST.setDate(31 - dayDST)
    endDST.setMonth(9)
    endDST.setHours(0)
    endDST.setDate(31)
    dayDST = endDST.getDay()
    endDST.setDate(31 - dayDST)
    var currentTime = new Date()
    currentTime.setMonth(month)
    currentTime.setYear(year)
    currentTime.setDate(day)
    currentTime.setHours(hr)
    if (currentTime >= startDST && currentTime < endDST) {
      dst = 1
    }

  }

  if (hr >= 9 && hr < 17) {
    status = "limegreen";
  }
  if (time.getDay() == 6 || time.getDay() == 0) {

    status = "red";
  } else {
    status = "red";
  }

  if (dst == 1) {
    hr -= 55 - 1
    if (hr >= 24) {
      hr = hr - 24
      day -= -1
    }
    if (hr < 10) {
      hr = " " + hr
    }

    if (day > monthDays[month]) {
      day = 1
      if (month == 11) {
        month = 0
        year -= -1
      } else {
        month -= -1
      }

    }


    return '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color: ' + status + ';"></i><br>' + monthArray[month] + " " + day + " " + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "<br>"
  } else {
    return '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color: ' + status + ';"></i><br>' + monthArray[month] + " " + day + " " + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "<br>"

  }
}

function worldClockZone() {
  document.getElementById("Newyork").innerHTML = worldClock(-5, "NAmerica")
  document.getElementById("London").innerHTML = worldClock(0, "Europe")
  document.getElementById("Tokyo").innerHTML = worldClock(-15, "Greenwich")
  document.getElementById("Sydney").innerHTML = worldClock(-14, "Greenwich")

  setTimeout("worldClockZone()", 1000)
}
window.onload = worldClockZone;
```

```html
<table style="margin-top: -12px; margin-right: 5px;">
<tr class="hrow">
<td><h5 style="font-size: 11px;">NY</h5>&nbsp;<span id="Newyork" class="user-status" style="font-size: 11px;"></span></td>

<td><h5 style="font-size: 10px;">London </h5>&nbsp;</i><span id="London" class="user-status" style="font-size: 11px;"></span><div style="border-left:1px solid #D3D3D3;height:40px;position: fixed; margin-top: -40px;"></div></td>

<td><h5 style="font-size: 11px;">Tokyo</h5>&nbsp;</i><span id="Tokyo" class="user-status" style="font-size: 11px;"></span><div style="border-left:1px solid #D3D3D3;height:40px;position: fixed; margin-top: -40px;"></div></td>
<td><h5 style="font-size: 11px;">Sydney</h5>&nbsp;<span id="Sydney" class="user-status" style="font-size: 11px;"></span><div style="border-left:1px solid #D3D3D3;height:40px;position: fixed; margin-top: -40px;"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the HTML on which the code runs. I've added a Stack Snippet, so you can click the "edit the above snippet" link and paste the HTML into the appropriate section.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey , sorry is my very first question here. I did edit my question with the respective html code just now but I am not sure if its right. I appreciate your review bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is in your evaluation of hr that leads to status. As written, status will always be red. Here's a fix :

```js
function worldClock(zone, region){
var dst = 0
var time = new Date()
var gmtMS = time.getTime() + (time.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
var gmtTime = new Date(gmtMS)
var day = gmtTime.getDate()
var month = gmtTime.getMonth()
var year = gmtTime.getYear()
if(year < 1000){
year += 1900
}
var monthArray = new Array("Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", 
                "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
var monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
if (year%4 == 0){
monthDays = new Array("31", "29", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
}
if(year%100 == 0 && year%400 != 0){
monthDays = new Array("31", "28", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31", "31", "30", "31", "30", "31")
}

var hr = gmtTime.getHours() + zone
var min = gmtTime.getMinutes()
var sec = gmtTime.getSeconds()

var status = new Array("")

if (hr >= 24){
hr = hr-24
day -= -1
}
if (hr < 0){
hr -= -24
day -= 1
}
if (hr < 10){
hr = " " + hr
}
if (min < 10){
min = "0" + min
}
if (sec < 10){
sec = "0" + sec
}
if (day <= 0){
if (month == 0){
    month = 11
    year -= 1
    }
    else{
    month = month -1
    }
day = monthDays[month]
}
if(day > monthDays[month]){
    day = 1
    if(month == 11){
    month = 0
    year -= -1
    }
    else{
    month -= -1
    }
}
if (region == "NAmerica"){
    var startDST = new Date()
    var endDST = new Date()
    startDST.setMonth(3)
    startDST.setHours(2)
    startDST.setDate(1)
    var dayDST = startDST.getDay()
    if (dayDST != 0){
        startDST.setDate(8-dayDST)
        }
        else{
        startDST.setDate(1)
        }
    endDST.setMonth(9)
    endDST.setHours(1)
    endDST.setDate(31)
    dayDST = endDST.getDay()
    endDST.setDate(31-dayDST)
    var currentTime = new Date()
    currentTime.setMonth(month)
    currentTime.setYear(year)
    currentTime.setDate(day)
    currentTime.setHours(hr)
    if(currentTime >= startDST && currentTime < endDST){
        dst = 1
        }
}
if (region == "Europe"){
    var startDST = new Date()
    var endDST = new Date()
    startDST.setMonth(2)
    startDST.setHours(1)
    startDST.setDate(31)
    var dayDST = startDST.getDay()
    startDST.setDate(31-dayDST)
    endDST.setMonth(9)
    endDST.setHours(0)
    endDST.setDate(31)
    dayDST = endDST.getDay()
    endDST.setDate(31-dayDST)
    var currentTime = new Date()
    currentTime.setMonth(month)
    currentTime.setYear(year)
    currentTime.setDate(day)
    currentTime.setHours(hr)
    if(currentTime >= startDST && currentTime < endDST){
        dst = 1
        }

}
    if(time.getDay() == 6 || time.getDay() == 0){
      status = "red";
    }
    else if (hr >= 9 && hr < 17) {
      status = "limegreen";
    }
    else {
      status = "red";
    }
    
if (dst == 1){
    hr -=55 -1
    if (hr >= 24){
    hr = hr-24
    day -= -1
    }
    if (hr < 10){
    hr = " " + hr
    }

    if(day > monthDays[month]){
    day = 1
    if(month == 11){
    month = 0
    year -= -1
    }
    else{
    month -= -1
    }

    }


return '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color: ' + status + ';"></i><br>' + monthArray[month] + " " + day + " " + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "<br>"
}
else{
return '<i class="fa fa-circle" style="color: ' + status + ';"></i><br>' + monthArray[month] + " " + day + " " + "<br>" + hr + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + "<br>"

}
}

function worldClockZone(){
document.getElementById("Newyork").innerHTML = worldClock(-5, "NAmerica")
document.getElementById("London").innerHTML = worldClock(0, "Europe")
document.getElementById("Tokyo").innerHTML = worldClock(-15, "Greenwich")
document.getElementById("Sydney").innerHTML = worldClock(-14, "Greenwich")

setTimeout("worldClockZone()", 1000)
}

worldClockZone()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/js/all.min.js"></script>

<div id="Newyork"></div>
<div id="London"></div>
<div id="Tokyo"></div>
<div id="Sydney"></div>
```

Comment: Man thank you so much for your reply. This solution seems to be working, as you say i was doing a wrong call for hr status i didnt noticed that. gezzz! 
I do have now to set a different time condition for each Region, it should be easy for me now. Once again Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

There are answers to your issue, buy your code seems very much more complex than it needs to be. Consider leveraging the Intl.DateTimeFormat constructor and [formatToParts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts). The following just uses time, you likely want to include the day of the week, holidays, etc.

```js
function isMarketOpen(loc, tz, open, close, date = new Date()) {
  // Get time in particular location for given date
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: tz,
    timeZoneName: 'short'
  });
  let {hour, minute, timeZoneName} = f.formatToParts(date).reduce((acc, part) => {
    if (part.type != "literal") {
      acc[part.type] = part.value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  // Return based on whether it's between open and close or not
  let time = hour*60 + minute*1;
  return `${loc} is ${time >= open && time <= close? 'open':'closed'} (${hour}:${minute} ${timeZoneName}).`;
}

// Sample data
let data = [
  {loc: 'New York',
   tz:  'America/New_York',
   open: 540, // Minutes
   close: 1020
  },{
   loc: 'London',
   tz:  'Europe/London',
   open: 480,
   close: 960
  }
];
// Show open/closed
data.forEach(obj => console.log(
  isMarketOpen(obj.loc, obj.tz, obj.open, obj.close)
));
```

Comment: Man I appreciate your time! The solution above by Bertrand seems to be working for me. But definitely I will test out your code, as it seems away more simple! Currently i just set conditions for if weekend or if x>y time , later i want to add multiple conditions for each Region as also specific dates of the year when the market is closed.